# Linux mint 15 mate boot screen change

Tags: linux, boot, linux-mint

Recently my boot up altered (HP Desktop) & now includes a screen that shows "ubuntu 15" showing pulsing 5 dots while it's loading. Then screen changes to my usual expected Mint tty1 boot screen. Login window unchanged. I do not have a dual boot arrangement.

Don't know why. Just prior to this I was clicking, too fast, through Netflix home screen. A direct result to this was "pulseadio" acting up. I usually use AlsaMixer. I removed pulse so have sound back.

This happened Nov 19, 2013.

If you require info from my terminal, you'll need to assist me with necessary commands.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this help? http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1149